Exterior and symmetric powers without choice
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $F$ a free $R$-Module and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Can it be proven in ZF that the canonical projections $F^{\otimes n}\twoheadrightarrow \bigwedge^n(F)$ and $F^{\otimes n}\twoheadrightarrow \text{Sym}^n(F)$ split?

They split if $n!$ is invertible in $R$, with a right-inverse being the antisymmetrization operator $v_1\wedge\ldots\wedge v_n\mapsto\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot  v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\ldots\otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$ and the analogous symmetrization operator.
We can prove them splitting in ZFC by installing a total order on some basis $(b_i)_{i\in I}$ of $F$ and work with the standard basis construction for exterior and symmetric powers, e.g. define $b_{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge b_{i_n}\mapsto b_{i_1}\otimes\ldots\otimes b_{i_n}$ for $i_1<\ldots < i_n$.

